# CMake compiler identification is unknown for MacOS 10.13.3

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, cmake

I want to build llvm via cmake,

and I use `cmake -G Xcode ../llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=MinSizeRel`.

But I'm in trouble.

The error log is:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0051 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Found assembler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/-ASM
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Moreover, I also use `xcrun -find cc`, result is `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc`

What can I do? Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have installed Xcode, try this:

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

Comment: saved my life !

Comment: Works like a charm on macOS 10.14.5 + XCode 10.1

Comment: It shew that after running this command: xcode: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Please, let try this:

- what version of CMake/Xcode is used? the most recent?
- pls. check if you don't have old/previous cmake build folder in source code
- if you upgrade Xcode, don't forget install command line tools again via

  sudo xcode-select --install
- a side-note: the CMake option 'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE' is useless for Xcode generator; this variable work only for Makefiles builds - remove it from command line and when the configuration will work, trigger the build via:

  cmake --build . --config MinSizeRel

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sudo xcodebuild -license`